# vba remove from collections while looping through them

Tags: excel, vba

What i have is a column that I used the match function in to generate the positions of found values. So each cell in that column will have a position value. ex. 3, 4, 5, #N/A, 7, 8, etc. Save for some cells with the value "#N/A" in there.

My goal is to generate a collection with these missing collection values. For example my collection would have the value "6" based on the above example. My current method is to fill a collection with all the possible positions and then loop through the column and remove based on the column cell's value.

```
Dim arrPos As New Collection
Dim bottomRow, matchRow As Long
bottomRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
matchRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' fill collection
For i = 3 To bottomRow
arrPos.Add i
Next i

' remove selects
For h = 3 To matchRow
    For g = 1 To arrPos.Count
    If Range("C" & h).Value = arrPos(g) Then
    arrPos.Remove (g)
    End If
    Next g
Next h
```

My issue is that I seem to be having trouble removing based on index while in loop. I get a `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` error on the `If` statement. I'm guessing this is because I am deleting while in loop and the indexes keep reordering. So why question is how to achieve these removals while in loop, or if there's a better way to achieve what I'm attempting.

Please note that these match results aren't in a perfectly ascending or descending order. so it'd actually look more like "5, 8, 4, 3, 7, #N/A, etc."

Comment: The issue here would seem to be that you add the values with the row number as the key but when you delete the items, you are deleting them by position. The row numbers start at 3 but the positions in the collection start at 1 so there's an obvious mismatch between the two. I'm not sure it's even possible to have integer values as keys in a collection because the default Item method seems to consider these values as positions rather than keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with the last position, and count backwards:

```
For h = matchRow To 3 Step -1
    For g = arrPos.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Range("C" & h).Value = arrPos(g) Then
            arrPos.Remove (g)
        End If
    Next g
Next h
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. i'm sure this is correct, but my results aren't coming out as intended. will accept in a second.

Comment: @mango - could you update your question with some sample rows and columns, the result you're getting, and the result you're expecting?  I'd be happier knowing my answer was accepted for actually helping with your problem :)

Comment: thanks for the concern. but i don't know how much of it I can divulge. I think i have to take a break from this today. And look with a fresh pair or eyes later. thank you again.